# Python converting string "1+2" to float

Tags: python, dataset

I'm beginner with Python, and I have problem with reading data from table.

Program can't convert string that contains addition of two numbers to float.

I get error `could not convert string to float: '6.8 + 3.9'`

I'm converting with this command

```
df['ScreenSize'].astype(np.float)
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I assume you want to add the two numbers and then store the result? If so, you can use `eval(s)`, which tries to treat `s` as a python expression and evaluate it. In your case, you could try `eval(df['ScreenSize'])`.

Comment: thanks, but now I get error that `eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object`

Comment: Right; sorry about that. Use `df['ScreenSize'].astype(str)`

Comment: you're welcome! I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`eval`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) function would be a perfect solution here. If you write `eval(df['ScreenSize'].astype(str)`, then python will attempt to treat the value returned by `df['ScreenSize']` as a python expression and evaluate it. If successful, the `eval` function will return the result.